# Make MyLocationOverlay compass point to a particular location

Tags: android, location, compass-geolocation, mylocationoverlay

I'm trying to make `MyLocationOverlay` compass to point to a particular location. I want to show a direction from current user's location to a given location. So far I've managed to calculate a direction and pass it to `MyLocationOverlay`. But the compass arrow starts pointing to different locations chaotically. Sometimes it points to the right direction but usually it shows complete nonsense. 
 
Is there a way to make the compass work as it should?
This is how I calculate the direction in my activity

```
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(location != null && carOverlay.size() > 0 
                && !map.getUserOverlay().isPointingToNorth()) {

            float azimuth = event.values[0];
            azimuth = azimuth * 180 / (float) Math.PI;
            GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(
                    Double.valueOf(location.getLatitude()).floatValue(),
                    Double.valueOf(location.getLongitude()).floatValue(),
                    Double.valueOf(location.getAltitude()).floatValue(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
            azimuth += geoField.getDeclination();

            GeoPoint point = carOverlay.getItem(0).getPoint();
            Location target = new Location(provider);
            float lat = (float) (point.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6f);
            float lon = (float) (point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6f);
            target.setLatitude(lat);
            target.setLongitude(lon);

            float bearing = location.bearingTo(target);
            float direction = azimuth - bearing;

            map.getUserOverlay().putCompassDirection(direction);
        }
    }
```

This is the overriden method in my custom overlay

```
@Override
    protected void drawCompass(Canvas canvas, float bearing) {
        if(pointToNorth) {
            super.drawCompass(canvas, bearing);
        }
        else {
            super.drawCompass(canvas, compassDirection);
        }

    }
```

Comment: "Sometimes it points to the right direction but usually it shows complete nonsense." Even a broken clock is right twice a day :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you calculate your "bearing/azimuth" yourself? MyLocationOverlay hold the Method getOrientation() to give you the azimuth. I would definetly leave `onSensorChanged` untouched, and let the `MyLocationOverlay` calculate this for you. Normally to draw your Compass correct you just have to call `enableCompass()`

Comment: I calculate the direction myself because I want the compass to point to a specific overlay item on the map. Basically, the user can toggle a button to either point the compass to north or to a location on the map.